# How to change IE input type="range" track block height

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-input

Is there a way to set the height of HTML input type="range" in IE? I mean the block height, not the track height. Here is what I have:

```
input[type=range]::-ms-track {
    width: 100%;
    height: 6px;
}
```

With above code I get a 6px height track, but the element block remains much higher as can be seen in the picture below, where I placed dotted borders to see the blocks:
[IE_Input_Range_Track_Height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnCAv.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the padding to 0

```
input[type=range] {padding: 0;}
```

http://codepen.io/rachelreveley/pen/Vjdyab

Comment: Thank you. Interesting only IE requires this fix. It did work just fine.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Spent quite some time figuring out why a custom styled slider was not shown in IE, the padding fixed it.